# Move selected mesh items to cursor in defined axis

Tags: python, scripting

I want to make a pie menu to snap selected parts of my mesh to the cursor constrained to specified directions. Example of snapping to cursor along x:
[image]

I would like to do this for x,y,z,xy,zx,yx. I don't know much scripting but I assumed that just subtracting locations would do the trick:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import math
import mathutils

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
cursor_location = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location

for v in bm.verts:
    v.co = cursor_location - v.co
    print(v.co)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

I'm probably doing something very wrong here, so I'd like some help if possible.

Comment: How to make it in graphic mode

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have figured it out by cobbling together a bunch of solutions.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

ob = bpy.context.object
ob.update_from_editmode()
me = ob.data
verts_sel = [v.co for v in me.vertices if v.select]
pivot = sum(verts_sel, Vector()) / len(verts_sel)
c_location = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
m_location = ob.matrix_world @ pivot

#get get the offset
l = c_location - m_location

#split the tuple
xdir = l[0]
ydir = l[1]
zdir = l[2]

#move the mesh in x to cursor
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(xdir, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL')
```